# C String got changed

Tags: c

I have a function

```
char *func1(char *buffer);
```

This is function has a buffer.

```
char buffer[10]={'\0'};
```

buffer is passed into the function and got the result from the function and returned from the function.

So, when the Main function called func1

```
char *result=func1(buffer);
```

so when I print the result, it gives a valid result..

```
 printf("The final result is %s", result);
```

However, after this line of code

```
   s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
```

I print the result again

```
   printf("The final result is %s", result);
```

This time it gives different result.

I am wondering why the `char * result` got changed?

Comment: please post the entire code with a test case showing the problem, my guess: you haven't noticed you've changed the values in the string

Comment: You're not showing us enough code here to tell.

Comment: inside func1 you have another buffer? which is local to that fuction?

Comment: It's really not possible to tell without the intervening code. *Something* there changed either the value of the pointer or what's in the array it points at. Provide some sample code that will actually manifest the problem, and describe what it outputs.

Comment: Where's _"some more codes"_ ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging while watching the contents of your `result`?

Comment: Most likely `buffer` is declared inside the function and then goes out of scope, so you are returning an invalid value.

Comment: OK, I added the line of code s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0); the result value got changed.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because your `buffer` went out of scope. You can't "hold on" to addresses of local variables, once they go out of scope the addresses become invalid.

As indicated by the stack of annoyed comments, this is impossible to really answer without seeing your code. Hopefully you should understand this, otherwise you're expecting magic here.

To allocate memory that persists regardless of scopes, allocate in on the heap using `malloc()`.

Comment: No, char buffer[10] is declared in the Main function. Not inside the func1.

Comment: @lilzz So you should post code to keep us all out of the mystery.